# Why was the static keyword used here?

Tags: c, language-design, keywords

In standard C, you have a few options for declaring a function that accepts a pointer to a chunk of data:

```
void style_1(int * arr);

void style_2(int arr[]);

void style_3(int arr[10]);

void style_4(int size, int arr[size]);

void style_5(int arr[static 10]);

void style_6(int size, int arr[static size]);
```

The thing is, as near as I can tell, most of the "choice" is syntactic and doesn't contribute much to the program's actual meaning. The first three styles appear to be exactly equivalent, because "A declaration of a parameter as 'array of *type*' shall be adjusted to 'qualified pointer to *type*'" (C11 6.7.6.3 p7), and `style_4` is also the same for the purposes of the pointer parameter. For both `style_3` and `style_4`, the array size is thrown away.

`style_5` and `style_6` are actually different and impose a useful constraint, guaranteeing a non-null pointer with a minimum amount of storage. But why do we need to add a keyword to do this? The declarations of `style_3` and `style_4` seem to communicate just as much information to the reader. A compiler would surely have no problem with those, if only the language allowed them to be meaningful? As it is, this design choice seems to introduce a hole that can allow extra errors to slip through, by effectively instructing the machine *not* to check for them by default.

Why was `static` added to impose the size constraint on array parameters in C? Why is the size on its own not sufficient?

Comment: It doesn't actually impose a *constraint* (the C standard uses that term to refer to rules whose violation must be diagnosed at compile time, along with syntax rules). Rather if a parameter is declared as `int arr[static 10]`, then passing an argument that doesn't point to the initial element of an array with at least 10 elements has undefined behavior. The point is to allow the compiler to optimize based on the assumption that the argument *does* properly point to such an object.

Answer (score 3):

For historical reason, in C (and C++) a parameter whose type is written as "array of type T" is actually a "pointer to type T". So `int arr [10]` just looks like the parameter is an array, in reality it is an `int*`. The size information is lost.

In C, if you write `int arr [static 10]` this turns into an `int*` pointing to 10 elements. Which would allow the compiler to invoke undefined behaviour if your read or write `arr[10]` or warn you if you assign to `arr[10]` with a constant 10.

Comment: I don't understand what is meant by this: "[...] or warn you if you assign to arr [10] with a constant 10.". Redundant with the previous clause?

Comment: As per this [site](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array), it is claimed that the size must be at least 10; anything less would be flagged as error (I assume compile time checking).

Answer (score 1):

Styles 5 and 6 were only added fairly recently to the C language (in the last decade or so), while the other styles have existed since the beginning for almost 30 years now.

When making changes to the C language, the committee doing so is very reluctant give new meaning to existing syntactic constructs, because it might break some existing code that used to be valid and with well-defined behavior.

That is the reason why styles 5 and 6 were added for the feature of passing an array with a guaranteed minimum size, rather than re-use styles 3 and 4.

Comment: I have a hard time imagining why any program would intentionally use styles 3 or 4 but not *want* to fulfil the implied contract. If the program documents the size of the array in the source, but doesn't live up to the documentation, isn't that just a bug?

Comment: @Leushenko: Most developers would indeed classify such a discrepancy as a bug, but according to the C language specification the behavior is perfectly well defined. If the behavior got changed, millions of lines of code would have to be evaluated if they are still correct according to the new specification. That can severely hinder the adoption of the new standard.